# Detection of Li-ion battery

Tags: battery

Can anyone explain how Li-ion battery are detected at airport security checking, and would it create any difference if the battery is discharged.

Comment: size, shape and density come to mind.

Comment: The X-ray profile and inductive properties of a battery will not vary with state of charge.

Comment: For the sake of your fellow passengers, please don't try to sneak Li-ion batteries on board.